# Duplicating rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

wonder if there's an easy way to duplicate rows in excel. An example would be:
Before:

```
1  
2  
3  
4
```

after:

```
1  
1  
2  
2  
3  
3  
4  
4
```

I meet this issue way to often to cut/paste my way down.. Anyone have a trick or two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggest you do an sorting your first result-set that includes each of your columns, e.g.

> Sort By Column A
>
> Then By Column B
>
> Then By Column C
>
> ...etc

This might give you something like:

```
1   A   X
2   B   Z
3   C   Y
4   D   T
```

Then you can copy the result set and paste it immedately below your first:

```
1   A   X
2   B   Z
3   C   Y
4   D   T
1   A   X
2   B   Z
3   C   Y
4   D   T
```

Then you would sort it again

```
1   A   X
1   A   X
2   B   Z
2   B   Z
3   C   Y
3   C   Y
4   D   T
4   D   T
```

Comment: your solution would give me:   
colA: 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4  
you solution plus an extra sort:  
colA: 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4  

This gives me what I need for my datasets, thanks alot m8 :)

Comment: My original post did include that, pbut somehow it got lost. Have edited accoringly.

Answer (score 2):

Initial state, many rows, many columns :

```
... ... ...
... ... ...
... ... ...
```

1. In an extra column, you add numbers from 1 to the number of rows :

   ```
   ... ... ...  1
   ... ... ...  2
   ... ... ...  3
   ```
2. Copy-paste the whole block below itself :

   ```
   ... ... ...  1
   ... ... ...  2
   ... ... ...  3
   ... ... ...  1
   ... ... ...  2
   ... ... ...  3
   ```
3. Order according to the last column :

   ```
   ... ... ...  1
   ... ... ...  1
   ... ... ...  2
   ... ... ...  2
   ... ... ...  3
   ... ... ...  3
   ```
4. You may now remove the extra column.